# C# XNA Weird error

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I've search google with no luck on this, maybe someone here could help as I really don't want to sign up on MSDN.

Every now and again I'll get this crash, I am not too sure what causes it.

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DeviceResourceManager.ReleaseAllReferences(UInt64 handle, Boolean dispose)
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DepthStencilBuffer.ReleaseNativeObject(Boolean disposeManagedResource)
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DepthStencilBuffer.!DepthStencilBuffer()
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DepthStencilBuffer.Dispose(Boolean )
at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.DepthStencilBuffer.Finalize()}
```

Using VS2008, C#, and XNA 3.1.

Edit: Here is the dispose code

```
protected override void UnloadContent()
{
   // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
   TileSet.Dispose(); // Tileset is no longer needed.
   blanksqaure.Dispose(); // Just for testing.
   Logo.Dispose(); //D ispose logo.
   AudioSystem.Dispose(); // Unload Audio System.
}
```

Comment: That's a little hard as the code has reached 15000 Lines.

Comment: Since its an error generated by the GC, can we see your dispose code?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean UnloadeContent()? I added it to my original post.

Comment: Have you tried running this code on other machines? The stack trace posted seems to start in the Finalizer and it's trying to free something it cannot access. I don't use XNA, but I do understand that it relies on DirectX, your video card, and video card drivers. It may be that there is a problem with some of these items and you need to isolate these as a possibility.

Comment: Do you have any finalize code?

Comment: @Brian Lyttle: I've never gotten this error on any other computer, and I believe you might be right about the video card drive on this one as it's an old computer. It happens at random too, and it wouldn't be the first time an application had problems with it.

@Soandos: No I do not. Not anywhere in any of the files.

Comment: Something your disposing has already been disposed

Comment: Objects should be able to be disposed many times without causing an error like this (it's part of the dispose pattern specification). I'd be surprised if any classes in XNA violated this rule...

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you say occasionally,  is there a chance that sometimes an Update/Draw call runs after this dispose?
2. Are you sure these are not loaded by Content.Load? By the looks of these names, they sure do look like game assets probably loaded by Content manager